# Identityserver4 protect/access api from/for outside users

Tags: angular, api, identityserver4, webapi

I want to give webapi access for the outside users(I mean, users not belongs to my organization). This API is already protected using identityserver4.

Our internal applications also using this API. Outside users want to access this API (same API for 2 applications) from their Angular application and .Net windows application. How do I give access for this?

API Resource --> **APISample**
API Scopes --> **api.read**, **api.write**

Kindly advise on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is a way for the outside users to register their "client-applications" with IdentityServer and agree on what scopes/claims should be present in the ID/access-token. Alternatively, you have to register the clients and give out the login details.

You can have this database driven, so its just a matter of adding the necessary records in the database. The code for this portal you have to do your self.

Comment: ok. got it. So if the outside client application is angular so I shd define the flow as code flow and if the user's applcaition is windows application the define the flow also as code like that, right? Lets say if the user is using Java application then how it shd define, any idea?

Comment: All the clients (regardless if it is angular/JavaScript/Java...) all they need is the URL to your IdentityServer and a clientID/secret.... And of course a list of allowed scopes to ask for.

Comment: Then it depends on what flow to use, if they want to use the authorization code flow (when your clients users wants to login) or client credentials flow (for service-to-service without any human involvement)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Have you implemented backchannel logout for all clients. I have some doubts on this.

Comment: The easiest is to just let the access-token expire, perhaps only give it a short lifetime, like a few minutes... alternatively your client can query identityserver (Token introspection) to check if a token is still valid. Finally, you can provide an url that will call the client during logout, see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/